# what is the use (role) of a couple of [] used in a namespace

Tags: c++-cli

I work on a big application used for trading and It is written with C++ and .Net.

I opened a .h file and I see something like below :

```
namespace Binary
{ 
  [ServiceModel::AutoServiceAttribute("string 1", BindingConfiguration = "string 2")]
....
....
}
```

I am not familiar with the use of double `[` in C++ progams like that, So:

1. what we call that syntactically.
2. what is it used for
3. is it related to Clr

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's rather `C++/CLI` thing. Sort of tags, I guess.

Comment: Is it `C++`?  Or is it `C++/CX` or `C++/CLI`?  Those are three different languages, with the latter two unfortunately having "C++" in them.

Comment: @Eljay C++/CLI i guess

Comment: It's an attribute, discoverable via reflection at run-time. It does relate to the namespace per se but rather to what follows immediately after.

Comment: Yes, exactly...